# How to generate POST and GET request by python twisted HTTPClient?

Tags: python, http, web, client, twisted

I am writing an HTTP Client. It is a simple mock bank site. It needs to be able to send two kinds of request out:

1. When user login:
   POST /login?user=bob&pass=abc123 
   HTTP/1.1 
   Host:  bank.com
2. When the user transfers money:
   GET /transfer?to=badguy&amt=100 
   HTTP/1.1 
   Host:  bank.com
   Cookie: login=fde874

I am implementing it by python twisted, I write a subclass of HTTPClient:

```
class BankClient(HTTPClient):
    def genReq():
       # How to write code to generate and send the Two request?

    def connectionMode(self):
        genReq()



class BankCllientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = BankClient
    def __init__(self):
       self.done = Defered()


def main(reactor):
   factory= BankClientFactory()
   reactor.connectTCP('localhost',8080,factory)
   return factory.done
if __name__ =='__main__':
    task.react(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop using `HTTPClient`.  Instead, use [`Agent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html#the-agent) or the third-party [`treq`](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/release-17.8.0/).

To generate `GET` and `POST` with `Agent`:

```
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.internet import reactor
agent = Agent(reactor)
d_get = agent.request(b"GET", uri)
d_post = agent.request(b"POST", uri)
```

To generate `GET` and `POST` with `treq`:

```
import treq
d_get = treq.get(url)
d_post = treq.post(url)
```